# return a list matching a search for a text string in ALL subjects, predicates and objects - in one query?

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, owl, allegrograph

I'm looking to return a list of matching URIs or text nodes that contain a certain text string in it.

This allows me to search for any subjects that have the matching string, but I want to also return any predicates or objects that match as well - all in the same query.

```
select ?s ?p ?o WHERE {
  ?s ?p ?o .
  FILTER (REGEX(STR(?s), "SEARCHTEXT", "i"))
}
```

Any idea how I could modify this?

Answer (score 3):

```
select ?s ?p ?o WHERE {
  ?s ?p ?o .
  FILTER ( REGEX(STR(?s), "SEARCHTEXT", "i") ||
           REGEX(STR(?p), "SEARCHTEXT", "i") ||
           REGEX(STR(?o), "SEARCHTEXT", "i") )
}
```

Comment: This would indeed work! Is there any way to get the results back as one column? I'm going to have to do some modifications to this result set to get a distinct array of possible results for "SEARCHTEXT" - removing the subjects, predicates, objects that don't match... thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

What use case do you intend this for? Since you want to search for it, your regular expression seems to express some valuable information about the tokens it matches on. If this is the case, it would seem sensible to mark up your data with some relation making this knowledge explicit!

A regex search as you intend seems sensible only in a very few cases, e.g. for a DBMS administration front end. If you just want to solve the problem, I would do something like this (in code, not as a query):

```
result = data.subjectSet().add(data.predicateSet()).add(data.objectSet())
FOREACH (token ε result) {
    result.remove(token) unless(token ≙ regex)
}
return result;
```

Comment: I wanted to do just a search for any entity that matched a given string - so URI's, text, etc. I thought it might be possible somehow with sparql - thanks!